# How can dialogs be opened and populated from dynamically mapped cards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I have an array of JSON data which is mapped to MUI cards.  The cards contain a button which opens a dialog.  I want to pass the value `GroupName` into the dialog when I click the button in the cards.  In actuality, I have 9 cards.  Each card has its own `GroupName` and associated data.  I need the button in each card to open one dialog populated with just the `GroupName` right now.

```
const [questionGroups, setQuestionGroups] = useState("");
const [qDialogOpen, setQDialogOpen] = useState(false);
const openQuestionsDialog = () => {
    setQDialogOpen(true);
};

const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setQDialogOpen(false);
};

function QuestionsDialog() {
    return (
        <Dialog open={qDialogOpen} onClose={handleDialogClose} maxWidth={"xl"}>
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">GROUP NAME HERE</DialogTitle>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleDialogClose}>OK</Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

This is how data is mapped to the cards

```
function DisplayCards() {
    return (
        <div>
            {questionGroups?.displaygroups?.IntakeValidations?.map((group, groupIndex) => {
                return (
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardHeader className={classes.cardTitle} title={group.GroupName} subheader={group.OwnerName} />
                        <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
                            <Button className={classes.cardBtns} onClick={openQuestionsDialog}>
                                Edit {group.GroupName} Answers
                            </Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is a shortened sample of my JSON:

```
{
  "displaygroups": {
    "IntakeValidations": [
      {
        "GroupId": 7,
        "GroupName": "DDD",
        "OwnerName": "Ciaran Crowley DDD",
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 8,
        "GroupName": "AAA",
        "OwnerName": "Ciaran Crowley AAA",
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 9,
        "GroupName": "BBB",
        "OwnerName": "Ciaran Crowley BBB",
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 10,
        "GroupName": "CCC",
        "OwnerName": "Ciaran Crowley CCC",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `groupName` in `qDialogOpen` state

```
<Button className={classes.cardBtns} onClick={() => openQuestionsDialog(group.GroupName)}>
    Edit {group.GroupName} Answers
</Button>

const [qDialogOpen, setQDialogOpen] = useState(false);
const openQuestionsDialog = (groupName) => {
    setQDialogOpen(groupName);
};

const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setQDialogOpen(false);
};

function QuestionsDialog() {
    return (
        <Dialog open={qDialogOpen} onClose={handleDialogClose} maxWidth={"xl"}>
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">{qDialogOpen}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleDialogClose}>OK</Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the object to the group open state, so instead of `useState(false)` use

```
const [qDialog, setQDialog] = useState(undefined);

const openQuestionsDialog = (group) => {
    setQDialog(group);
};

const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setQDialog(undefined);
};

<Button className={classes.cardBtns} onClick={() => openQuestionsDialog(group)}>Edit {group.GroupName} Answers</Button>


<Dialog open={qDialog !== undefined} onClose={handleDialogClose} maxWidth={"xl"}>
    {qDialog !== undefined && <>
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">{qDialog.groupName</DialogTitle>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleDialogClose}>OK</Button>
            </DialogActions>
     </>}
</Dialog>
```

Let me know if this helps